# International flight - Changing airport and airline in New york

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, jfk, lga

I'm looking at an international flight and the return segment involves changing airports from John F. Kennedy Airport (JFK) to LaGuardia Airport (LGA). The airline changes as well, from British Airways to Virgin America.

If I purchase this ticket from [Skyscanner Ltd.](http://www.skyscanner.net) and if there is a delay, will I be taken care of and put on a different flight on Virgin America, or does that become my responsibility at that point?

Comment: If it's the same itinerary and there is a delay then airlines usually do their best to accommodate getting you there.  Problem is You have to get from JFK to LGA, which is not their responsibility.

Comment: So basically, I'm guessing there is no guarantee with such a ticket which involves an airport change.

Comment: @edocetirwi The airlines will usually have a minimum connecting time (MCT) between the airports.  If your incoming flight is so delayed that you have less than the MCT left to transfer, they should put you on a later flight.

Comment: I'd suggest buying that ticket from a "bricks and mortar" travel agent, rather than an OTA (online travel agent). A proper travel agent can get it all on one ticket, which would mean you'd be protected against delays. If it's on two different tickets, then you'd be on your own

Comment: I have never seen a single ticket with an airport change and different airlines. I have seen such a ticket on British Airways, where the ticket even included ground transportation between LGW and LHR, and I assume BA takes responsibility for any delays. The layover was, IIRC, over 3 hours. But there may *be* such a ticket. The question is if this is one joint ticket sold by one airline, or two. In the latter case, you will be on your own. Which case applies should be clear from Skyscanner's description of the ticket.

Comment: @edocetirwi Depending on the day of the week and time of the day your transfer time may vary widely between JFK and LGA on the best of days.  And given construction currently in LGA and on Van Wyck I'd avoid a ticket like this

Comment: Is it actually possible to buy a ticket from SkyScanner? I'd tought they were just a search engine - I've always been forwarded to an OTA or airline site when I went to buy on there.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I've seen one with an AA flight into LHR, Aer Lingus flight from LGW to Dublin, on 125 (BA) stock. Can be done!

Comment: @Karlson I think the issue is whether whatever airline Skyscanner sends you to, will be writing this as a single ticket. For round trips, Kayak, a Skyscanner competitor, sometimes sends you to one airline for outbound and the other for the return. As long as this is written as a single ticket by the issuing airline, I think the OP is protected in case of delay/misconnect.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus I looked at it again and they are going to send me to Hop2. Not sure whether Hop2 would write this as a single ticket or as a split one. I'm not buying this anyways, since I feel this is too much risk for too little return. Thank you all.

Comment: Leave lots of time. The two airports are a 1/2hour apart and there can be traffic jams due to rush hour or accidents that can double that time.  You also need time to collect you bags and check them again.  So, leave lots of time!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are booking two separate flights - one to JFK; and then another separate trip outbound from LGA.

These are unrelated; which means that your luggage won't be checked through, and you'll have to check in at LGA to receive your boarding pass for the second flight.

So to answer your question regarding the delay - it is solely your responsibility as Virgin America will not have any knowledge of your British Airways flight - even if you told them; they are not liable for any compensation to you.

Comment: VIrgin America and British Airlines have an "interline agreement", which is what matters when it comes to booking a single ticket.  It has nothing to do with "partner" airlines.  That's not to say that this isn't 2 tickets, but your reason for assuming it is (and thus your answer) is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that interline agreement? I don't see a reference for it anywhere.

Comment: Agreed with BurhanKhalid - I can't find details of it anywhere @Doc?